# How to sort a dict by one of its values in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dict like this:
key is a string,
value is a list of strings

```
    my_dict = {
    'key1': [value11, value12, value13],
    'key2': [value21, value22, value23],
    'key3': [value31, value32, value33],
    'key4': [value41, value42, value43]
}
```

e.g.

```
dict_0 = {
'key1' : [lv, 2, abc],
'key2' : [ab, 4, abc],
'key3' : [xj, 1, abc],
'key4' : [om, 3, abc],
}
```

I wanted to be sorted based on the second value in the value list, so, it should be like this:

```
dict_0 = {
'key3' : [xj, 1, abc],
'key1' : [lv, 2, abc],
'key4' : [om, 3, abc],
'key2' : [ab, 4, abc],
}
```

I want to sort this dict by one of the value in the value list, i.e. value*2, how can I do this?
I've searched extensively on the site, but didn't find a similar case.

Thanks.

Comment: Dictionaries are unordered.

Comment: You can't sort a dictionary.  A dictionary has hashable keys that provide access to its values.  There is something called and OrderedDict which you may look at

Comment: You can't. Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/sort-a-python-dictionary-by-value for a possible solution, or use an Ordered Dictionary

Comment: A dictionary can have a sorted _string representation_, but it itself cannot be inherently sorted i.e. `for i in dictionary` doesn't guarantee any order.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dictionaries are not ordered data structures, if you want a sorted one you can use `OrderedDict()` function from `collections` module.

```
>>> dict_0 = {
... 'key1' : ['lv', 2, 'abc'],
... 'key2' : ['ab', 4, 'abc'],
... 'key3' : ['xj', 1, 'abc'],
... 'key4' : ['om', 3, 'abc'],
... }

>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> OrderedDict(sorted(dict_0.items(), key=lambda x: x[1][1]))
OrderedDict([('key3', ['xj', 1, 'abc']),
             ('key1', ['lv', 2, 'abc']),
             ('key4', ['om', 3, 'abc']),
             ('key2', ['ab', 4, 'abc'])])
>>>
```

Comment: Beautifully solved my problem! Accepted, thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])
```

This will sort the dictionary by the values of each entry within the dictionary from smallest to largest.